# convert for loop from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, for-loop

I have following loop in C#

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
{}
```

This is part of the levenshtein algorithm which I use but not clearly understand (off topic)
I need to translate this line to vb.net.
Cant seem to make sure which of both loops i need to use:

```
for i as integer to n step 1
  d(i,0) = i
next
```

or

```
for i as integer to n step 1
 d(i,0) = i +1
next
```

Comment: First one seems ok, you should try it yourself

Comment: Have you tried google: [C#+VB](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Have you tried it? It gives a horrible result ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be:

```
For i As Integer 0 To n
  d(i,0) = i
Next
```

In `d[i, 0] = i++`, `d[i, 0]` gets the value of `i` *before* it's incremented, so the VB loop should do the same.

Comment: Thanks was not sure when the increment took place. Was hard to test because I need to rewrite a ton of c# in to vb.net, crazy I know.

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent VB.NET code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To n
    d(i,0) = i
Next
```

Comment: How does the threading and `Max` work its way in here?